# Check if the values in the df matches any of the values of the dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

df -

| orderid | supplierid | name | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | x |  |
| 102 | 1 | z |  |
| 103 | 2 | x |  |

dict -

```
{1: {'name': ['x', 'y']},
 2: {'name': ['z']}}
```

My end goal is to check if the name given for a particular id matches any of the values in the dict or not and populate a new column "exist_or_not" with yes or no for the same.

Expected result -

| orderid | supplierid | name | exist_or_not |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | x | yes |
| 102 | 1 | z | no |
| 103 | 2 | x | no |

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create DataFrame with nested list comprehension first, then use left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter and last create `yes, no` in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
d = {1: {'name': ['x', 'y']}, 2: {'name': ['z']}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(k, x) 
                   for k, v in d.items() 
                   for k1, v1 in v.items() 
                   for x in v1], columns=['supplierid','name'])
print (df1)
   supplierid name
0           1    x
1           1    y
2           2    z
```

---

```
df = df.merge(df1, on=['supplierid','name'], how='left', indicator='exist_or_not')

df['exist_or_not'] = np.where(df['exist_or_not'].eq('both'), 'yes', 'no')
print (df)
   orderid  supplierid name exist_or_not
0      101           1    x          yes
1      102           1    z           no
2      103           2    x           no
```

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension

```
df["exists_or_not"] = ["yes"
                       if the_name in d[sup_id]["name"]
                       else "no"
                       for the_name, sup_id in zip(df.name, df.supplierid)]
```

where `d` is your dictionary `{1: {'name': ['x', 'y']}, 2: {'name': ['z']}}`.

to get

```
   orderid  supplierid name exists_or_not
0      101           1    x           yes
1      102           1    z            no
2      103           2    x            no
```